# How do I access variables(objects) that are create within a for loop and apply it in another function?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, scope

```
ngOnInit() {

    let ingredientInfo = [];
    let ingredientId = [];
    let ingredient = {};
    let ingredients = [];

    let params1 = URL
    this.activeIngredient = this.api.httpGet(`Item/DropboxList${params1}`).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(data =>{
      for ( let i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
        
        ingredientInfo = data[i].ListInfo;
        ingredientId = data[0].ListOrder;

        ingredient = {Id: ingredientId, Info: ingredientInfo};

        ingredients.push(ingredient);
        // console.log("Chemical Name: ",ingredients[255]);
      }
      console.log("Chemical Name: ",ingredients);
    });//: active Ingredient
}

    this.formservice.getOnToolbarPreparing().pipe(skipWhile(value => value === null), takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(value => {
      value.toolbarOptions.items.unshift(
        {
          location: "before",
          widget: "dxSelectBox",
          options: {
            width: 150,
            visible: true,
            placeholder: "Please Select",
            datasource: ingredients,
            // valueExpr: 'Id',
            displayExpr: ingredientInfo
          }
        }
      )
    });//: getOnToolbar preparing
```

The variable ingredients will be an array of objects at the end of the loop. But I would like to have the last record of it as a datasource for the SelectBox. But it seems that I can't have access to it due to scope issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared variables inside of `ngOnInit()`, and are attempting to use them outside of `ngOnInit()`. Just declare them as a property of the component, or put your other code inside the method in which these variables exist.

```js
  ingredients: any[] = [];
  ingredient = {};
  ingredientInfo: any[] = [];
  
  ngOnInit() {
    let ingredientId = [];

    let params1 = URL;
    this.activeIngredient = this.api
      .httpGet(`Item/DropboxList${params1}`)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
          this.ingredientInfo = data[i].ListInfo;
          ingredientId = data[0].ListOrder;

          this.ingredient = { Id: ingredientId, Info: this.ingredientInfo };

          this.ingredients.push(this.ingredient);
        }
        console.log('Chemical Name: ', this.ingredients);
      }); //: active Ingredient
  }

  someFn() {
    this.formservice
      .getOnToolbarPreparing()
      .pipe(
        skipWhile((value) => value === null),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe((value: any) => {
        value.toolbarOptions.items.unshift({
          location: 'before',
          widget: 'dxSelectBox',
          options: {
            width: 150,
            visible: true,
            placeholder: 'Please Select',
            datasource: this.ingredients,
            displayExpr: this.ingredientInfo,
          },
        });
      }); //: getOnToolbar preparing
  }
```

**OR**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let ingredientInfo: any[] = [];
    let ingredientId = [];
    let ingredient = {};
    let ingredients: any[] = [];

    let params1 = URL;
    this.activeIngredient = this.api
      .httpGet(`Item/DropboxList${params1}`)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
          ingredientInfo = data[i].ListInfo;
          ingredientId = data[0].ListOrder;

          ingredient = { Id: ingredientId, Info: ingredientInfo };

          ingredients.push(ingredient);
        }
        console.log('Chemical Name: ', ingredients);
      }); //: active Ingredient

    this.formservice
      .getOnToolbarPreparing()
      .pipe(
        skipWhile((value) => value === null),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe((value: any) => {
        value.toolbarOptions.items.unshift({
          location: 'before',
          widget: 'dxSelectBox',
          options: {
            width: 150,
            visible: true,
            placeholder: 'Please Select',
            datasource: ingredients,
            displayExpr: ingredientInfo,
          },
        });
      }); //: getOnToolbar preparing
  }
```